# Promise.all and building axios requests inside async function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, axios

I'm looping data to build multiple axios requests and in this async loop is an await for some data.

When I do this, `Promise.all` resolves before an error is thrown on one of the requests `.catch(errror => {})` I purposely gave one bad data so the request would go to catch.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let requestArr = [];
    requestsData.forEach(async (data) => {
        let waitForThisData = await someFunction(data.id);
        requestArr.push(
            axios
             .post()
             .then((response) => {})
             .catch((error) => {})
        );
    });

    Promise.all(requestArr).then(() => {
        resolve(true);
    });
});
```

I'm testing this with 3 requests, 1 of which will go to catch. When I added breakpoints `Promise.all` already resolves before going to one of the requests catch.

If I remove the await code then I get my expected output, catch triggers first before the `Promise.all` resolves.

So why does Promise.all resolve before one of the request finishes(errors and goes to catch)?

Comment: So is your question "why does `Promise.all` resolve before the `catch` gets triggered inside the `forEach` loop"? What's your desired behavior?

Comment: @codemonkey Sorry, yes. made that more clear in my question.

Comment: Are you only interested to know why or are you actually trying to figure out a way to catch errors before the `Promise.all` resolves? I don't have much to offer as regards the former, but if it's the latter, I can suggest a few changes that will make your code behave in a way that makes sense.

Comment: It might help to post what output you are getting by including console statements in your functions above, not sure I fully understand the problem

Comment: @codemonkey the latter would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: So to be sure, if one or more of the axios requests goes to catch, do you not want that promise to be pushed into your `requestArr` array? Or do you want the whole function to bomb? How exactly do you want the code to behave?

Comment: @codemonkey I want it to be pushed. I want to push every request in requestArr and `Promise.all` should only resolve when all requests finishes(succesfully or error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make your `Promise.all` resolve AFTER the catch inside the loop, or, indeed, after all the requests (successful or unsuccessful):

```
const axios = require('axios');

const someFunction = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('222'), 100)
    })
}

const requestsData = ['https://httpstat.us/200', 'https://httpstat.us/205', 'https://httpstat.us/306']
const requestArr = requestsData.map(async data => {
    let waitForThisData = await someFunction(data);
    return axios.post(data)
            .then(response => {})
            .catch(error => console.log(error.toString()))
});

Promise.all(requestArr).then(() => {
    console.log('resolved promise.all')
})
```

`https://httpstat.us/306` will produce an erroneous call. You can try placing it anywhere within the `requestsData` array.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But the only difference I see is it's now using map, how did that make a difference?

Comment: @crimson589 Great question. The `Promise.all` in your code actually tries to resolve an empty array. It is reached before your `forEach` loop has a chance to push anything into `requestArr` variable. Small wonder it resolves before any of your axios calls. In contrast `map` populates `requestArr` with whatever is returned from its function (promises in our case) before moving on to the next line. That's what makes the difference. This, incidentally, is also pointed out by Todd Skelton in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are pushing promises to the `requestArr` asynchronously, so if you call `promise.all` on the array before it's filled. It's going to resolve when the promises in it resolve. By removing the `await` you are quickly pushing all the requests to the `requestArr`.

So to answer your question, it resolves because all of the requests in `requestArr` have resolved before the `requestArr.push()` has been called on your error promise.

You can try to use your own `async` `foreach` function to do this a better way.

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

Now you can `await` the `foreach` before calling the `Promise.all()`.

```
let requestArr = [];

await asyncForEach(requestsData, async (data) => {
    let waitForThisData = await someFunction(data.id);
    requestArr.push(
        axios
            .post()
            .then((response) => { })
            .catch((error) => { })
    );
});

Promise.all(requestArr).then(() => {
    resolve(true);
});
```

Comment: I see, after reviewing my code I can see it now. There's a portion I didn't include in my example above, there's actually some validation before the await statement. Not everything in the loop would go through the await statement, so the code has gone through everything in the loop but one of them is still "awaiting" and hasn't been pushed to the `requestArr` yet when `Promise.all` executes.